# Android SpeechRecognizer Enable Formatting / Punctuation

Tags: speech-to-text, android-speech-api

Has anybody tried to implement the automatic text formatting (punctuation) of recognitation results from Android SpeechRecognizer?
It is decribed [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent#EXTRA_ENABLE_FORMATTING).

According to the documentation it should be activated via putExtra:

```
recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ENABLE_FORMATTING, true);
```

The documentation says: "Depending on the recognizer implementation, this value may have no effect."

But how to get the effect of formatting? With this basic approach of "putExtra" it doesnt work for me. I have tested it in several apps but I dont get any formatted result.

Thank you!